# Credentials. C# authorization in Silverlight application

Tags: c#, wpf, iis, browser, credentials

I have Basic Authentication on IIS. My WPF app use WebBrowser to connect to Silverlight application published on IIS. And I try different ways to predefine credentials. 
Like that:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://1.1.1.1/MyApp");
byte[] authData = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user: password");
string authHeader = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authData) + "\r\n";
this.browser.Navigate(uri, "", null, authHeader);
```

But the problem that doesnt work. All I can this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
CredentialCache credentials = new CredentialCache();
credentials.Add(
   uri, "Basic",
   new NetworkCredential("user", "password"));
   request.Credentials = credentials;
   request.PreAuthenticate = true;
   WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
   this.browser.NavigateToStream(response.GetResponseStream());
```

But in that case I cant use Silverlight.js and all other styles and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this by providing your WebBrowser control with a custom *IOleClientSite* object which also implements *IServiceProvider* and *IAuthenticate* interfaces. Through *IAuthenticate* you'd supply your credentials. This approach involves some hacks. You could refer to this excellent blog [post](http://chrismabry.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/wpf-and-the-webbrowser-control/) for the implementation details.

Comment: this didnt help me, to difficult
But now I know that my credentials and authentication dont work only on silverlight applications, and that all okey when I pubich just index.html file